# How do I build a long If Condition with an Array and the && condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

Before I had:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < t1Children.length; i++) {
          return checkIdentical( t1Children[i], t2Children[i] );
      }
```

But I don't know how to chain the && conditions of each "i" together using the for loop pattern.

The below works how I want it to, but I need to keep adding on t2Children[2],[3], etc manually.

```
      return ( ( checkIdentical( t1Children[0], t2Children[0] ) ) && ( checkIdentical( t1Children[1], t2Children[1] ) ) );
```

How do I iterate in a way such that I can chain &&'s together? Any suggestions?

Comment: consider [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as a solution ... `var result = t1Children.every((t1, index)  => checkIdentical(t1, t2Children[index]));`

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, Are you trying to compare each element in one array to each element in the other?

Comment: Now I think I know what you mean, see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var result = true;
for (var i = 0; i < t1Children.length; i++) {
     result = result && checkIdentical( t1Children[i], t2Children[i] );
}
```

Comment: Please note that my answer should stop calling checkIdentical() once the variable result becomes false, which may save a little bit of time for a negative answer and still the same for the positive all identical result. If it's a must to have checkIdentical() being called for ALL elements, please don't use this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allEqual = true;
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    if(array1[i] != array2[i]){
         allEqual = false;
         break;
    }
}
return allEqual;
```

This should work as allEqual will remain true if all the elements are equal, otherwise it will return false